# Failed to load module during vmware installation

Tags: installation, vmware-player, kali-linux

I have installed kali rolling 64 bit. I wanted to install vmware workstation pro (i.e version 12 latest one). During installation i am facing following error

Extracting VMware Installer...done.

Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge": /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0: undefined symbol: g_type_class_adjust_private_offset
(vmware-installer.py:4062):

Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine", (repeating around 20 lines)

Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

i have done

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-*
sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2.4-1c2
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines:i386
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-*:i386
sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2.4-1c2:i386
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
```

but error still exists.
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so this file exists there
How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, but the installer is launch and work.

Look at the task bar for a 'VMware Installer' application:

[Launched icon where launch VMWare installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRjQZ.png)

It seems it was just a warning.